# I wonder why i can't add picture to the .img class (through the css) and why the sign up button wont change to sign in when i click it

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image][image]I follow this youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sy9OI-ndKnc). I don't understand HTML, CSS, and JS that much (to be honest i had no experience in it), but I really need this page to work. I think the .img-btn span.m-in should be the one responsible to translate the button when it get clicked(?).

```js
document.querySelector('.img-btn').addEventListener('click', function()
 {
  document.querySelector('.cont').classList.toggle('s-signup')
 }
);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700;800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading li,a,button{
 font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
 display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 10%;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.heading .logo{
 cursor: pointer;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation{
 list-style: none;
}

.navigation li{
 display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.navigation li a{
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.navigation li a:hover{
    color: #0088a9;
}

.heading button{
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgb(224, 173, 19);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;   
}

.heading button:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,136,168,0.8);
}

.joinus{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000000, #FF0000);
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.joinus input, button{
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 background: none;
}

.cont{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 width: 900px;
 height: 550px;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.form{
 position: relative;
 width: 640px;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 50px 30px;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.joinus h2{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.joinus label{
 display: block;
 width: 260px;
 margin: 25px auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.joinus label span{
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: #505f75;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.joinus input{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(109, 93, 93, 0.4);
 text-align: center; 
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.joinus button{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 260px;
 height: 36px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.submit{
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 background-color: rgb(224, 173, 19);
}

.submit:hover{
 background-color: rgba(0,136,168,0.8);
}

.forgot-pass{
 margin-top: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 600px;
 color: #0c0101;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.forgot-pass:hover{
 color: rgba(0,136,168,0.8);
}

.social-media{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.social-media ul{
 list-style: none;
}

.social-media ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 25px 15px;
}

.social-media img{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
}

.sub-cont{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 640px;
 top: 0;
 width: 900px;
 height: 100%;
 padding-left: 260px;
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.cont.s-signup .sub-cont{
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-640px, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-640px, 0, 0);
}

.img{
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 260px;
 height: 100%;
 padding-top: 360px;
}

.img:before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 900px;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url(img/alex.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.img:after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.cont .s-signup .img:before{
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(640px, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(640px, 0, 0);
}

.img-text{
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.img-text h2{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-weight: normal;
}

.img-text p{
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

.cont.s-signup .img-text.m-up{
 -webkit-transform: translateX(520px);
   transform: translateX(520px);
}

.img-text.m-in{
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-520px);
   transform: translateX(-520px);
}

.cont.s-signup .img-text.m-in{
 -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
   transform:translateX(0);
}

.sign-in{
 padding-top: 65px;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.cont.s-signup .sign-in{
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
   transition-duration: 1.2s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(640px, 0 , 0);
   transform: translate3d(640px, 0 , 0);
}

.img-btn{
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 2;
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 height: 36px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: transparent;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.img-btn:after{
 content: '';
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50px;
}

.img-btn span{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s;
 transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s;
 transition: transform 1.2s;
 transition: transform 1.2s, -webkit-transform 1.2s;
} 

.img-btn span.m-in{
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-72px);
   transform: translateY(-72px);
}

.sign-up{
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-900px, 0 ,0);
   transform: translate3d(-900px, 0, 0);
}

.cont.s-signup .sign-up{
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0 ,0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Join us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/joinus.css">
</head>
<body>

<section class="heading">
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo_csc.png" alt="logo"></a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="navigation">
          <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
          <a href="about.html"><li>About us</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>Research</li></a>
           <a href="#"><li>Our Achievement</li></a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    <div>
      <a href="joinus.html"><button>Join us</button></a>    
    </div>
  </header>
</section>

<section class="joinus">
   <div class="cont">
       <div class="form sign-in">
           <h2>Sign In</h2>
           <label>
               <span>Email Address</span>
               <input type="email" name="email">
           </label>
           <label>
               <span>Password</span>
               <input type="password" name="password">
           </label>
           <button class="submit" type="button">Sign In</button> 
           <p class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password?</p>

           <div class="social-media">
               <ul>
                   <li><img src="img/instagram.png"></li>
                   <li><img src="img/youtube.png"></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="sub-cont">
           <div class="img">
               <div class="img-text m-up">
                   <h2>New activist?</h2>
                   <p>Sign up here!</p>
               </div>
               <div class="img-text m-in">
                   <h2>Already an activist?</h2>
                   <p>If you already has an account, sign in here!.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="img-btn">
                   <span class="m-up">Sign Up</span>
                   <span class="m-in">Sign In</span>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form sign-up">
               <h2>Sign  Up</h2>
               <label>
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name...">
               </label>
               <label>
                   <input type="email" placeholder="Email...">
               </label>
               <label>
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Majors...">
               </label>
               <label>
                   <input type="password" placeholder="Password...">
               </label>
               <label>
                   <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password...">
               </label>
               <button type="button" class="submit">Sign Up Now</button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</section> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/register.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Codepen https://codepen.io/thisisloop/pen/xxwadPp

I had to add these two codes to the CSS File:

```
.cont.s-signup .img-btn span.m-in{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}
.cont.s-signup .img-btn span.m-up{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(72px);
            transform: translateY(72px);
}
```

For the image, you need to add quotation marks 
instead of:

```
background-image: url(img/alex.jpg);
```

do

```
background-image: url('img/alex.jpg');
```

I couldnt add it to the codepen, because codepen doesnt allow file upload for free users.

Comment: The image is there on my pc, sorry I didn't give the file detailed and there's an img folder, thank you for your answer, i will try to fix the JS

Comment: Nope, changing the JS doesn't make it work. It made the code doesn't work at all instead. .img-btn is the correct class for this purpose

Comment: If you look at the tutorial when you click the sign-up img-button on the right side, your page will smoothly transition to the sign-up page, and the sign-up button will go to the left side and change into "sign-in" and when you click it, it will do the otherwise.

Comment: I created a codepen https://codepen.io/thisisloop/pen/xxwadPp and it does work for me, is this what your code should do?

Comment: The "Sign up" should change to "Sign in" when it translate. I add a picture to make it clearer

Comment: I got it to work, check my initial answer!
Would be nice if you could accept my answer as correct.

Comment: sorry it was very late at my place, thank you so much for your solution sir!

Comment: the button change works! Thanks!, but I still can't use the picture, but that's enough I guess, Thank you so much!